# Using splines to address non-linearity in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, splines, diagnostic

I was wondering if the following is a reasonable way to proceed:

I have a number of logistic models, fitted using `glm`, that I want to use to make predictions. The models have a continuous variable (call it `cont_var`), and for some of the models, a [Box-Tidwell test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217471/why-does-including-x-lnx-interaction-term-in-logistic-regression-model-helps) suggests a non-linear relationship between `cont_var` and the logit of the outcome.

Should I worry? Here's what I'm thinking:

For any model where there might be non-linearity, I use `splines` to fit that model, replacing `cont_var` with `ns(cont_var, df = 4)`. Then, I make the same predictions I made with the original, non-spline model, and see if they give radically different predictions. If not, I conclude that any non-linearity isn't affecting my predictions.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Personally, I'd use `mgcv::gam` and let it choose the dfs (you can simply add the non-splines in the same way as in `glm`). That way you get its guess of the degree of non-linearity. When the edf (estimated d.f.) are around 1, cont_var has a near-linear effect and the glm is fine.

Comment: very interesting question. I wonder if we use spline basis on logistic regression, what does the decision boundary looks like ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that makes sense. For a post doing this, and showing some plots, see [Make Nonlinear Smooth Interpretable in Logistic GAM Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430606/make-nonlinear-smooth-interpretable-in-logistic-gam-regression).  You should not only compare the predictions numerically, but look at plots of the estimated nonlinear smooth.

For how to do formal tests, see [Anova on logistic regressions linearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217643/anova-on-logistic-regressions-linearity). [Here is a list of other relevant Qs with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logist*+regres*+splin*+*lin*+answers%3A1).