# Dealing with Continuous Variable in Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, data-preprocessing

I Am trying to create a Logistic model and I have two columns which are important features but it has continuous values ... I have 7044 rows so creating dummies might not be optimal which will burst whole lot of columns ...
What should be My approach ... Any suggestions ...?

```
   PaymentMethod          MonthlyCharges    TotalCharges    Churn
  Electronic check          29.85              29.85          No
   Mailed check             56.95             1889.5          No
    Mailed check            53.85             108.15          Yes
```

Comment: A logistic regression requires a binary dependent variable but continuous predictors are no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Continuous predictors are fine with logistic regression. But, linear effects is a strong assumption with logistic regression, so it might be a good idea to spline the continuous predictors.    See [Using splines to address non-linearity in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449690/using-splines-to-address-non-linearity-in-logistic-regression)  and its links.

Your question contains little details and context, so if you want more advice, please update the post with details.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn