# Variable Importance Plot & Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, importance

I am trying to predict whether client would take up a promotion or not using the random forest model. From the variable importance plot output, it is shown that the number of days pass the day of contact(which I bin in days of 5) is the most important variable in the predictive modelling.

However, when I put this into a hypothesis testing, chi square test, the p-value is greater than 0.05. How do I reconcile these two facts or if there is a better way of testing that the number of days in relation to whether client would take up a promotion?

Comment: how do you perform the chi^2 test?

Comment: @rep_ho that would be chi^2 test on the categorical variables: ContactDay & Yes/No

Comment: Might be the case that the effect is confounded by other variables.  Generally though, the p value does not tell you how important a variable is or if its effect is large or not.

Answer (score 2):

You lost information by binning, see [Why should binning be avoided at all costs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390705/why-should-binning-be-avoided-at-all-costs). For an alternative, use logistic regression and spline the `day of contact` variable. For details see [Logistic Regression with regression splines in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122212/logistic-regression-with-regression-splines-in-r)  or   [Using splines to address non-linearity in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449690/using-splines-to-address-non-linearity-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried logistic regression before but the accuracy rate is not as good as the random forest model. I would just like to check if using any other hypothesis method would be good for testing

Comment: Then please edit the post to give some more info, like other covariables, sample size, show us a plot, ...